# Setting a key shortcut for Launchpad in Lion

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, launchpad

Is it possible to set a key shortcut to open Launchpad in Lion? I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In System Preferences -> Keyboard,

[image]

You can set a shortcut. Note that initially the shortcut is blank, so just double click on the space where the shortcut should be and you can edit it.

Comment: Thanks again, just totally missed this preference pane. For awhile I was double-clicking on the name of the shortcut...

Comment: Maybe I can reciprocate: after pressing Cmd+Shift+4 to capture a region of the screen, press the spacebar to capture a single window.

Comment: Ahahaha yea, I knew that. Though I found out pretty recently, so I haven't changed my habits yet!